# .Net 6.0. Dependency Injection. How do I inject by type?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I have multiple implementations of an ICombiService interface. I want to inject one of these implementations based on a string value from appsettings.json.  I can find the configured type thus

```
private static Type? GetConfiguredCombiServiceType(Settings settings)
{
    var type = typeof(ICombiService);
    var cst = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .FirstOrDefault(p => !p.IsInterface && type.IsAssignableFrom(p) 
                                            && p.Name.Contains(settings.CombiSpecification));
    return cst;
}
```

How do I then inject this configured type?  I have searched extensively, (maybe I'm wording my search wrong) but not finding anything. I want to end up with something like the following

```
var builder = new ServiceCollection()

    // Other dependencies here . . .

    .AddTransient<ICombiService>(cs => (ICombiService)combiService)
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

but that's a spurious cast and does not work. This kind of thing is easy enough with AutoFac and Ninject but I can't seem to find any info on Microsofts implementation of DI. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm embarrassed to say, the answer is as simple as

```
var combiService = GetConfiguredCombiServiceType(settings);
```

then in your builder...

```
var builder = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient(typeof(ICombiService), combiService)
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```